# How to exclude forward slash in deeplinking with pathAdvancedPattern using regex in android

Tags: android, regex, deep-linking

There are few URL paths in below format:

```
demo.com/log/
demo.com/logData1
demo.com/logSub2
and many more as such
```

and below is my data block of manifest:

```
<data
                    android:host="@string/deeplink_host"
                    android:pathAdvancedPattern="/log[^/].*"
                    android:scheme="https" />
```

The above regex matches '/log/' even after using "^/".
How should the regex look like if it should not match "/log/"

I tried to allow android app to open only few URLs which has URL path starting with '/log' but not '/log/'. But even after using '^/' in the regex, it is still matching '/log/'

Answer (score -1):

In regex, you have to escape a slash with a backslash (`/` -> `\/`)

But apparently `\` is used as an escape character when the string is read from XML¹, so you need to double the backslashes.

So in your case:

```
\\/log[^\\/].*
▲▲      ▲▲
││      ││
└┴──────┴┴─── Add backslashes here
```

[link to regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tru7sf/1)

¹ https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#path

Comment: As u mentioned, I already tried using android:pathAdvancedPattern="\/log[^\/].*" but the app is still getting opened on clicking demo.com/log/

It is working fine in regex. I'm only concerned about Android's Deeplinking regex with pathAdvancedPattern in manifest

Comment: @Sandiri try double-escaping, like this: `\\/`